# proving a language is in NP/EXPTIME/Turing decider/turing recognizable (cs theory)

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

prepping for my cs theory exam by running through a practice test. I nthe problem, I need to state in which "zone" a language belongs to (RL/DFSA/NFSA)/(CFG/CFL/NPDA)/(NP)/(EXPTIME)/(DL/DTM/NDTM)/(TR) 
and I realized im not sure how to prove what a language would be past the (CFG/CFL/NPDA) zone. Here are 2 problems (3 and 5) that I know cannot be in that zone since they would fail the pumping lemma for context free langages, how could i determine what zone they would fall under?

---

EDIT: The answersare that both 3 and 5 both fall into NP, but why?

[image]

Comment: Better suited to cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No. cstheory.SE is for research-level questions, not elementary "is this language a CFL?" and "is this language in NP?" kind of problems (not that there's anything bad about these questions, just that they do not fall in cstheory.SE's scope).

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that you can prove that 3 and 5 are not in the NPDA zone. Pick up from there. You move on to the next, NP. Here on out, you work with variously restricted turing machines.

I can recognize language 3 in linear time with logarithmic space. Count the a symbols. Count the b symbols. Count the c symbols. Compare the counts. That's a linear scan through the data plus a comparison of binary numbers (which is less than linear time for the input length). Linear time is a subset of NP. How detailed would your professor require you to be (i.e. do you need to explicitly introduce a third alphabet symbol to separate your counts? Do you need to spell out how to compare binary numbers?)?

To solve 5, you'll need to know the bounds of binary multiplication. Count a, count b, count c. Multiply the count of a by the count of b. Compare the result to the count of c. That's a linear scan through the input plus whatever the complexity of binary multiplication is (but remember that the numbers you are multiplying are log(n) bits). Since your zone isn't very restrictive, let's at least say we're bound by polynomial time. Since P is a subset of NP, we're there.

Any higher than this, and I'd expect that you'll get more wordy descriptions of problems. I assume that PSPACE is in your EXPTIME zone, and the canonical example that comes to mind is quantified boolean formula. It's sort of like SAT (Cook's theorem proves SAT is NP-Hard), but with quantifiers. There's a nice proof to show QBF is PSPACE complete that is quite analogous to Cook's theorem. I'm guessing that your context sensitive languages that do not obviously belong to a subset in another zone also belong here (in case you get a production rule description of the language).

The next zone is Turing machines that halt. If you can describe an algorithm, no matter how ridiculous (and it *must* be ridiculous, or it would have been caught by a previous zone), it can stop here.

The next zone is all about Rice's theorem. Wiki that bad boy. All proofs are easy again with Rice's theorem. This zone is easier than coming up with a regex or FSA for the first zone.